# Open Graph / Facebook: Keep IDN URL instead of ACE Strings by posting on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph, idn

I have a international Domain with german "umlauts" (german special characters).

When posting/linking on Facebook the original Domainname (IDN) is shown as ACE String (something "translated" URL maybe for DNS without special german chars) at the bottom for the Server destination linked.

Is it possible to keep the IDN, by passing something special (og:url) to facebook, to tell that the IDN HAS TO BE USED instead of the ACE String? Technically its not neccessary to translate to ACE.

I don't want something translated to be shown because customers may be irritated.

Thank you.
Chris

Comment: It might not be _technically_ necessary to show the Punycode version – but it often done to prevent possible spoofing attempts … so that is maybe just the price you have to pay for using an IDN, if Facebook decides to display it that way. You could try and specify the site name and publisher as well – in the hope that FB substitutes the URL for one of those when displaying the link, or at least shows them in addition to the punycode version …

Comment: Or, if you have a second domain without the umlaut in it (but it rewritten as ae/ue/oe) as “fallback”, then you could see to it that that version gets shared instead … and maybe redirect users that follow that shared link to the IDN version again, if vanity demands it.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Seems i have to live with that.